# Where can I find the database for Summer of Nhibernate tutorials?

Tags: nhibernate

I am trying to learn from the screencast videos of [Summer of Nhibernate](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/) and I am in the third video. The tutorials have never until now given / shown the full view of Database and I am worried that there might be fields missing in my mocked up DB. Now I am going through data manipulation techniques and I need to have data in all 4 tables.

Where / How can I find that demo database? I searched in the site entirely, searched on google, no leads.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have mappings you can generate it with SchemaExport.

Comment: good idea, I think I can find the mappings in the code section. Great, thanks. (I'm having a face-palm moment, why didn't I think of that?!)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate database schema and script file in this way:

```
        var conf = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
        conf.Configure();


        var export = new SchemaExport(conf);
        export.SetOutputFile(@"DatabaseScript.sql");
        export.Drop(true, true);
        export.Create(true, true);
```